# ListView and AddRange

Tags: c#, linq, listview, telerik

Using `AddRange` in a `ListView` When you have a **custom collection** and want to add **2 columns (properties)** of the collection Items to the `ListView`

Preferably do this via `Telerik ListView`

a similar code- it is not correct because of this line :

```
ListViewDataItem(wi.Name, wi.ID)
```

I want a better approach if possible

```
        ListViewDataItem[] elements ;
        ListViewDataItem lvi; 
        int c = 0 ;
        Collection.ForEach(wi =>
        {
            lvi = new ListViewDataItem(wi.Name, wi.ID);
            elements[c]  = lvi ;
            c += 1 ;
            //LvCollection.Items.Add(wi.Name, wi.ID);
        });

        LvCollection.Items.AddRange(elements);
```

thanks,
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but looking at the [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/m_telerik_wincontrols_ui_listviewdataitem__ctor_3.html) something like

```
LvCollection.Items.AddRange( 
    Collection.Select(wi => new ListViewDataItem( 
        wi.Name, new string[]{wi.ID.ToString()} ) ).ToArray() );
```

or

```
LvCollection.Items.AddRange( 
    Collection.Select(wi => new ListViewDataItem( 
        'test', new string[]{wi.Name, wi.ID.ToString()} ) ).ToArray() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lvCollection is the ListView, and wi is an item of our custom collection, I'll try it and let you know

Comment: It seems near to what it should be, but still errors about parameters, I think we should change the position of "new ListViewDataItem(" to the top of the snippet, I'm nbot good at linq, could you give a refreshed version of it, thanks +1

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItemCollection.AddRange(params Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItem[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The Collection is a class wrapping this collection :

Comment: public List<ColItem> TheCollection{ get; set; }

Comment: Looks like AddRange requires an Array.  Added .ToArray()

Comment: It worked ! thanks a lot bro, I will ask another complementary question about this when we want to fill it in a cross-thread format next day, hope you also participate in it, thanks a ton again